# ./gradlew connectedVariantNameAndroidTest failed

Tags: android-studio, gradle, instrumented-test

At Android studio's terminal key in "./gradlew connectedVariantNameAndroidTest".
Result with following error message:

> > Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
>
> > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

From error message, you should connect a device using usb or a virtual device.

Comment: Thank you, CoXier.But how to connect a device?

Comment: If you have Android device, you can use usb to connect pc and Android device.

Comment: To CoXier. After connect to my real android mobile with android studio through wifi, "./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest" command success in android studio's terminal .But I would like to use this command on Jenkins later, how could I let Jenkins connect to Android real or virtual device???

Comment: You can use virtual device such as emulator on Jenkins.